# Display Multiple appointement per day from database in html table

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I use Codeigniter 3 and bootstrap 3, i have a table RDV (Doctor Appointment) in database i want to display doctor appointment in a view from data base.
i want the output should look like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|DATE               | TIME               | EVENT         | PATIENT        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2016-06-13         | 03:28              |Consultation   |IHAB BARI       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   | 05:00              |Viste          |ISSHAK KOMA     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   | 06:15              |Esthetique     |ABASS DOSSO     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2016-07-17         | 08:10              |Visite         |KOKO TASSI      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the table in database : ID | DATE | HEURE_RDV | MOTIF_RDV | PATIENT | DETAIL_RDV

in a model  i have this code :

```
public function rdv_selectAll_mdl()
{

    $query = $this->db->get('rdv');
    return $query;
}
```

in controller :

```
public function rdv_selectAll()
{

    $this->load->model('calender_model');

    $query = $this->calender_model->rdv_selectAll_mdl();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[$row->dateRdv][] = $row->heureRdv;
        $data[$row->dateRdv][] = $row->patientRdv;
        $data[$row->dateRdv][] = $row->motifRdv;
        $data[$row->dateRdv][] = $row->detailRdv;
    }

    $this->load->view('gs_calender');

}
```

with this controller i tried to put the time and event and patient and detail in one date im not sure if it is correct or not , im think about a multidimentionnel array to put multi rows in one row and use the rowspan in html table,if its correct how can loop in view  any one can help me with a solution please.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do :

```
$data['rdv'] = $query->result_array(); 
$this->load->view('gs_calender',$data);
```

and then inside of view

```
foreach($rdv as $r){
//echo your columns for every row 
}
```

or if you want this to be even better, you can use table library, check it here:

> https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

with table library you would do something like :

```
$this->load->library('table');

//add bootstrap class to table 
$tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table class="table">' );
$this->table->set_template($tmpl);

//get your table
$data['rdv'] = $query->result_array();

//add table th
$this->table->set_heading('Date','Time','Event','Patient');

//loop inside of results
foreach($data['rdv'] as $t){
            $this->table->add_row($t['date'],$t['time'],$t['event'],$t['patient']);
        }

//generate table and pass it to view
$data['table'] = $this->table->generate();
$this->load->view('gs_calender',$data);
```

and then inside of view just do

```
echo $table;
```

edit for question inside of comment :

```
$daterd="";
    //loop inside of results
    foreach($data['rdv'] as $t){

  if($daterd == $t['dateRdv']){  
       $t['dateRdv'] = "";
                } 
  else {$daterd = $t['dateRdv'];}

$this->table->add_row($t['dateRdv'],$t['heureRdv'],$t['patient_id'],$t['detailRdv']);
                    $t['dateRdv']="";


            }
```

Comment: thank you in advance for your reply, i think in output date will be repeated for evry row, i want one date and multi events, if im wrong please told me how i can loop in view

Comment: Just read my answer again, I edited stuff and for yo to loop in view you have to pass `$data['rdv'] = $query->result_array(); ` to view `$this->load->view('gs_calender',$data);`

Comment: As I told you the column date repeated for every row

Comment: i want to display if i have 2 rows in same date using rowspan

Comment: You can add variable at the end of foreach `$date = $r['date']` and at beggning of foreach you can ask `if($date == $r['date']) { echo "<td>".$r['date']."</td>";} else { echo "<td></td>"}`  and you have to add `$date="";` before entering foreach

Comment: i have error in $date=""; Message: Undefined index: date

Comment: Well `$r['nameofcoulmn']` change that `['date']` with your column names from table

Comment: the date still  repeated

Comment: my fault, change `if($date == $r['date'])` to `if($date != $r['date'])` just change == to !=

Comment: i think the echo echo "<td>".$r['date']."</td>"; has no effect on table library

Comment: I didn't know you changed to table library, you can do it like this `if($date != $r['yourcoulmndate']) { } else { $r['yourcoulmndate' = "";}` add this before `$this->table->add_row($t['yourcolumndate'],$t['time'],$t['event'],$t['patient']);`

Comment: sorry marco i have made error code i put $this->table->add_row($t['yourcolumndate'],$t['time'],$t['event'],$t['patient']‌​); before $r['yourcoulmndate'] = ""; now its working

Comment: i edited my answer with "edit for question inside of comment :"  check that part it is better than your edit, and we can close this question